# Google App Engine doesn't work with Hardhat

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, hardhat

I have a Node.js (express) server, which on request deploys a smart contract using Hardhat library. It works locally, but if I deploy it to Google App Engine and make a request I get a cors error and error 500.
Is it even possible to deploy a Hardhat project?

This is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors({
  origin: '*',
  methods: '*',
  allowedHeaders: '*',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}));
module.exports = app

app.post("/", async(req,res) =>{ 
    console.log("Get from /"); 
    console.log(req.body.data);
    
      const HelloWorld = await ethers.getContractFactory("HelloWorld");  
    // Start deployment, returning a promise that resolves to a contract object
     const hello_world = await HelloWorld.deploy("naslov tukaj");   

    console.log("Contract deployed to address:", hello_world.address);

    const contract = require("../artifacts/contracts/HelloWorld.sol/HelloWorld.json");
    res.send("res send");
      
                            });

// starting the server
app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('listening on port 8080');
});
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hardhat-project",
 
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "hello world smart contract",
  "main": "hardhat.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.0.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.6",
    "ethers": "^5.6.9",
    "hardhat": "^2.9.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Error:
[image: Error]

Response header:
[image]

App.yaml:

```
service: mint
runtime: nodejs16
```

*New headers:
[image: headers]

Comment: What is the exact CORS error? What is the `origin` header in the request? When testing locally check to see which CORS headers, if any, are being returned. If you do have a CORS problem, usually the server must be modified either by adding support for CORS or configuring the server to return the correct CORS headers that match the request. Your code is not required, the request and response headers are required.

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you for your answer. Locally, I this CORS header is returned: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * . The origin header in the request is my localhost from where I am making the request. I also added the screenshot of the error and the headers to the post.

Comment: Can you also share your configuration on `app.yaml` file?

Comment: @SarahRemo I added the configuration to the post. But after I added the handlers I can't deploy. I get the error unknown url handler type.

Comment: Your updated code is crashing. The HTTP Status Code is 500. Look into the logs to see which line has failed or test the app locally first.

Comment: @JohnHanley locally everything works. Only when I try to make a request to the deployed site I get error 500.

Comment: Are you saying your new code works locally and now crashes in App Engine? Check the App Engine logs for more details.

Comment: @JohnHanley if I remove all hardhat code and require(ethers) then the deployed app works fine. But when I add it, I get the error 500.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: If your code is crashing, then that must be solved first before looking at CORS related issues. The CORS headers are probably not being sent due to your application crashing (error 500).

Comment: @JohnHanley the error is always the same as the screenshot I posted in the question. But in the network I get status 500.

Comment: You need to look at the error generated by the application and not what you see in the web browser. The web browser is showing you the **second** problem (CORS). You need to solve the first problem (code crash).

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you very much! It solved the problem. I checked the App Engine logs and saw that a dotenv module wasn't found. I taught it all worked, since there wasn't a problem locally. You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATE]

The problem with CORS was caused by the application crashing. The app crash was caused by a missing dotenv module.

When an application crashes, the CORS headers are not sent. The browser only sees that the CORS preflight failed and reports a CORS error masking the real problem.

[END UPDATE]

The request has two CORS headers: `access-control-request-headers` and `access-control-request-method`. The response has no CORS headers. That is the reason for the CORS error.

The origin is `http://localhost:3000`. The response should be `access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000` or `access-control-allow-origin: *`. The latter is not recommended but is useful to debug CORS while you tighten security.

The headers subject to CORS are `content-type`. The response should be `access-control-request-headers: content-type` or `access-control-request-headers: *`.

The HTTP method is `POST`. The response should be `access-control-request-method: POST` or `access-control-request-method: *`.

Those three CORS headers need to be returned in order for the CORS preflight to succeed.

Change your code to be as follows (for getting started/debugging):

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*',
    methods: '*',
    allowedHeaders: '*',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}));
```

The line `optionsSuccessStatus: 200` is optional. Some browsers do not like 204. Modern browsers do not need that setting.

If that works, then start adjusting the CORS options to tighten security, which is the purpose of CORS.

For example, these options are very tight:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    methods: ['POST'],
    allowedHeaders: 'content-type'
}));
```

There are other options that you can pass to `cors(options)`.

[Cors Configuration Options](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuration-options)

Within a route, you can also set the CORS headers manually. For example:

```
app.post("/", async(req,res) =>{ 
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Method', '*');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

    // More code here

    res.send("send res");
});
```

Note: App Engine also supports enabling CORS via the app.yaml `http_headers`.

[app.yaml Configuration File](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed the code as you suggested, but I keep getting the same errors. I also tried adding the http_headers to app.yaml, but I can't deploy. I get the error: unknown url handler type. I added the app.yaml file to the original question.

Comment: @Nina Decide on which method to use `app.yaml` or Node.js `cors`. Do not use both. Make that objective clear in your question.

Comment: I would rather use Node.js cors, but I just tried app.yaml, because it wasn't working.

Comment: @Nina, update your question with the code that you are now using and the request/response headers. Also, update the entire app.yaml so that I know how your app is configured.

Comment: I added the headers and updated the code and app.yaml